# Return results in Google Scholar with more than 25 citations

Tags: search

Is there a way to run a search in Google Scholar that only returns results that have more than 25 citations?

Most of the good papers have at least 25 citations, but [Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.com) returns mostly results with 0-3 citations.

Is there a way to seach for +25 citations?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to restrict the results in Google Scholar by citation number, to my knowledge.  However, it is useful to understand that Scholar heavily weights the number of citations in deciding which results to return.  For a broad search one can see this; the returned results will tend to be in order of decreasing number of citations.  When narrow searches are done, as by using many search terms, this ordering is often not seen, presumably because the search engine finds closer term matches in obscure papers with few citations.  Sometimes one can choose alternative queries which are broad enough to include the more heavily cited papers in the field.

Some insight into how the Google Scholar search engine works is available in this paper: [Beel, J. Google Scholar's Ranking Algorithm: An Introductory Overview](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBoQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sciplore.org%2Fpublications%2F2009-Google_Scholar%27s_Ranking_Algorithm_--_An_Introductory_Overview_--_preprint.pdf&ei=TPVZTZD-F4O8sAO9luSRCg&usg=AFQjCNFtStCZddN_wYsSpKFukMhEvm0isQ)